# Is a listbox.item an object or a string? C#

Tags: c#, string, object, listbox

Received the following question in a exam today and I had no idea:

Is a `listbox.item` a string or an object?

Could somebody help clear this up?

Comment: Read the doc. They made it for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this and get idea,
its an object
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

also you can use list for FindString

```
    private void FindMyString(string searchString)
{
   // Ensure we have a proper string to search for. 
   if (searchString != string.Empty)
   {
      // Find the item in the list and store the index to the item. 
      int index = listBox1.FindString(searchString);
      // Determine if a valid index is returned. Select the item if it is valid. 
      if (index != -1)
         listBox1.SetSelected(index,true);
      else
         MessageBox.Show("The search string did not match any items in the ListBox");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an object

[ListBox.Items Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if (listBox1.DataSource == null)
        {
            // ----- items are string
        }
        else
        {
            //----items are object
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to check if datasource is null?

Comment: @nilesh sir. if items are added in list box then datasource will be null and if datasource is assigned to listbox then datasource will not be null